# Getting avalondock and wpf ribbon to work on vs2010

Tags: wpf, ribbon, avalondock

I'm trying to make Avalon work with WPF Ribbon on VS2010 .NET 4, but all I got is a blank screen overriding even the titlebar. I think this problem is caused by some incompatibility with the RibbonWindow tag, instead of Window. I looked at these posts:

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=62562
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=68265

but none solved my problem. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the ribbon tag inside the DockPanel tag before the DockingManager.